# Need ordinal cluster-inbound-channel-adapter with poller [not for ftp]. Still couldn't found

Tags: spring-integration

I have trouble with the setting up inbound-channel-adapter in cluster environment in legacy project.
Each node is running the code and I am getting bad results with it.

So I need to prevent it running except for 1 node.
I am not so familiar with spring-integration and and after reading a tons of docs I found only the cluster solution for the ftp. but I have no ftp and not need to depend on it here.

So is there any cluster solution for the ordinal inbound-channel-adapter, or at least with jdbc if there is nothing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use zookeeper and a `SmartLifecycleRoleController` to elect one instance as the leader.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#leadership-event-handling).